# Upgrading workflows from 2007 to 2010

Tags: upgrade, workflow, 2007

Are there any "gothchas" when upgrading workflows from 2007 to 2010:

- In place upgrade on server
- Conversion of VS Solution
- What happens to running workflows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of my Workflows worked fine after upgrading. The only problems I had were with third-party addons. "Extended lookup" from codeplex wouldn't even allow me to open the list with one column using it. I couldn't delete it either. If you have any third party addons, either remove them or make sure they will work in 2010 first.